# How to assign delegates as methods of some implemented interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface, delegates

Say I have an interface that specifies two void methods with no parameters. How can I "plug" two `System.Action(T)` methods in some class that implements the interface? In my example below, this would be in the `void PushFoo(Action bar1, Action bar2)` method:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar1();
    void Bar2();
}

public class Bla
{
    Stack<IFoo> _fooStack = new Stack<IFoo>();

    public void PushFoo(IFoo foo)
    {
        _fooStack.Push(foo);
    }

    public void PushFoo(Action bar1, Action bar2)
    {
        IFoo foo = null;

        // assign bar1 and bar2 to foo
        //foo = ... ;

        _fooStack.Push(foo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Other than Kek's answer (which would've been mine too :) ) I wonder if there's a way to do this without writing a wrapper per interface, via reflection...

Comment: Maybe thanks to a dynamic proxy... but reflection alone won't let you instaciate interfaces... (or at least not easily)

Comment: @Kek Who said anything about "easily"? :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
public Class ActionableFoo : IFoo
{
    Action _bar1, _bar2;

    public ActionableFoo(Action b1, Action b2)
    {
        _bar1 = b1;
        _bar2 = b2;
    }

    public void Bar1() { if(_bar1 != null) _bar1(); }
    public void Bar2() { if(_bar2 != null) _bar2(); }
}
```

Then , in your example:

```
public void PushFoo(Action bar1, Action bar2)
{
    IFoo foo = new ActionableFoo(bar1, bar2);
    _fooStack.Push(foo);
}
```

Comment: Welcome... this is the exact principle of RelayCommand in WPF MVVM : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This piqued my interest, so here's a method that uses reflection to build a wrapper around a set of delegates (or rather `Func`/`Action`s) that also implements a given interface.

```
Type GenerateInterfaceImplementator<TInterface>()
{
    var interfaceType = typeof(TInterface);
    var funcTypes = interfaceType.GetMethods()
        .Select(GenerateFuncOrAction).ToArray();


    AssemblyName aName =
        new AssemblyName("Dynamic" + interfaceType.Name + "WrapperAssembly");
    var assBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(
            aName,
            AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);

    var modBuilder = assBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(aName.Name);

    TypeBuilder typeBuilder = modBuilder.DefineType(
        "Dynamic" + interfaceType.Name + "Wrapper",
            TypeAttributes.Public);

    // Define a constructor taking the same parameters as this method.
    var ctrBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineConstructor(
        MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
            MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.RTSpecialName,
        CallingConventions.Standard,
        funcTypes);


    // Start building the constructor.
    var ctrGenerator = ctrBuilder.GetILGenerator();
    ctrGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
    ctrGenerator.Emit(
        OpCodes.Call,
        typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));

    // For each interface method, we add a field to hold the supplied
    // delegate, code to store it in the constructor, and an
    // implementation that calls the delegate.
    byte methodIndex = 0;
    foreach (var interfaceMethod in interfaceType.GetMethods())
    {
        ctrBuilder.DefineParameter(
            methodIndex + 1,
            ParameterAttributes.None,
            "del_" + interfaceMethod.Name);

        var delegateField = typeBuilder.DefineField(
            "del_" + interfaceMethod.Name,
            funcTypes[methodIndex],
            FieldAttributes.Private);

        ctrGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        ctrGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, methodIndex + 1);
        ctrGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, delegateField);

        var metBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod(
            interfaceMethod.Name,
            MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Virtual |
                MethodAttributes.Final | MethodAttributes.HideBySig |
                MethodAttributes.NewSlot,
            interfaceMethod.ReturnType,
            interfaceMethod.GetParameters()
                .Select(p => p.ParameterType).ToArray());

        var metGenerator = metBuilder.GetILGenerator();
        metGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        metGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, delegateField);

        // Generate code to load each parameter.
        byte paramIndex = 1;
        foreach (var param in interfaceMethod.GetParameters())
        {
            metGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_S, paramIndex);
            paramIndex++;
        }
        metGenerator.EmitCall(
            OpCodes.Callvirt,
            funcTypes[methodIndex].GetMethod("Invoke"),
            null);

        metGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        methodIndex++;
    }

    ctrGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    // Add interface implementation and finish creating.
    typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(interfaceType);
    var wrapperType = typeBuilder.CreateType();

    // Return an instance using the constructor we created.
    return wrapperType;
}
```

The function `Type GenerateFuncOrAction(MethodInfo method)` isn't shown here because it's horrible - you have to switch on the number of parameters the method has and also on whether it returns void or not.

The generator is called as follows:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void M1();
    string M2(int m2, string n2);
    string P { get; set; }
}

...

var iType = GenerateInterfaceImplementator<ITest>();
var instance = (ITest)Activator.CreateInstance(iType,
    new Action(() => { Console.WriteLine("M1 called");  return; }),
    new Func<int, string, string>((ij, xjx) => xjx + ij.ToString()),
    new Func<String>(() => "P getter called"),
    new Action<string>(s => { Console.WriteLine(s); }));

instance.M1();
Console.WriteLine(instance.M2(6, "you are number "));
instance.P = "P setter called";
Console.WriteLine(instance.P);
```

This is the first time I've really used `Reflection.Emit` so all comments welcome.

An issue is that you have to know the order in which the interface methods will be supplied by `GetMethods`.

Comment: does this work if I add to the interface? say I add string property? Btw, `assBuilder`, funny ;-)

Comment: This totally doesn't cover properties! I knew I'd forgotten something, lol. If you add a new method to the interface you have to add a `Action`/`Func` type to the generator call, otherwise you'll get a runtime error when you call the generator. If someone figures out the improvement I've suggested, you'd only have to supply a new lambda to the call to `CreateInstance`.

Comment: @Ludo Actually, this does cover properties! You just have to know to supply a `Func<T>` and/or an `Action<T>` (the getter and the setter, respectively), and again you have to know where they will come in the order returned by `GetMethods`.

Comment: Nice! it might be overkill for a simple use case, but it's reusable... +1

Comment: I really appreciate the spirit in which I think you are doing this: answer the question as it was asked (+1 btw).

Comment: @Ludo I was originally going to answer as Kek did, but he beat me to it, so I just decided to do this as it's been nagging at me for a while. N.B. This will also handle events in the delegate; you have to add two `Action<EventHandlerType>` for the handler-added and handler-removed functions ^^

Comment: Also: this totally isn't an attempt to one-up @Kek's answer, which is much easier-to-understand, more robust and doubtless more performant. The only reason I can think of for using this instead is as a prototyping or testing tool.

Comment: yes I know that Kek's answer is a better solution (and answer); I was just saying this as I sincerely appreciate when ppl answer questions as they were asked as opposed to posting answers telling to just do things in some other way.